# Apache directs https:b-site visitor to https:a-site (b-site don't have ssl)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, https

I've got an issue with my apache system.
it's brand new, and so are I.

my problem now is that if somebody visit https://123.446.689.0 or https://b-site.com,  (which don't have any ssl), then will a-site cut in on the https...

How can a connection jump like that? (of course a warning comes up, since the ssl is for another domain)

I WILL get ssl on b-site to, but can't get a ssl to the ip.
and all direct IP access should be redirect to another site. (which currently is 000-default)

these are my configuration files;

**a-site.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost a-site.com:80>
ServerName a-site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/a-site.com
    <Directory /var/www/a-site.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/a-site.com/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-site.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-site.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =a-site.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**a-conf.com-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost a-site.com:443>
    ServerName a-site.com
    ServerAdmin arga@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/a-site.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-site.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-site.access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/a-site.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/a-site.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 123.456.789.0:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/00
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/catchall.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/catchall.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**b-site.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost b-site.com:80>
ServerName b-site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/b-site.com
    <Directory /var/www/b-site.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/b-site.com/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/b-site.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/b-site.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**000-default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/00
            
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/napto.def.error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/napto.def.access.log combined
            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>             
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added a new site, called 00al... but now does the 00al site intercept the a-sites https... what's happening? how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only `a-site.com:443` `VirtualHost` defined for port 443 (https) so Apache shows only the site it can find to show.

You need to define a default `VirtualHost` on port 443 `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` the same way as you have in `000-default.conf` (or check if you have `default-ssl.conf` and enable it). You still need a TLS/SSL certificate for the default host but you can create a self-signed certificate. Debian-based systems already have one generated for you as `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem`.

Comment: Actually, I have one, and when but there's no difference if it's activated or not, I even tried to rename it to 000-def... so it would be before then a-site, but the a site still intercept the https://123.456.789.0 call..

Comment: actually, it was my tires eyes, I had actually written .conf instead of .com in the  virtualhost line..., and when I censured the address in the question, the error wanished, but I have your answer as correct, as it is on this question..